# How can I fix this NoReverseMatch error?

Tags: python, django

```
Error Message:*<br/><br/>
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'get_travel_details' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'origin': u'bus_terminals.Bus_Terminal_Id', u'destination': u'bus_terminals.Bus_Terminal_Id', u'travel_date': u'travel_date'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P< travel_date >\\w+)/travel_date/(?P< origin >\\w+)/origin/(?P< destination >\\w+)/destination']
```

I am trying to pass values to the url's parameters through the form action, this is what my form tag looks in my html file:

```
<form method = "POST" action ="{% url 'brats:get_travel_details' travel_date='travel_date' origin='bus_terminals.Bus_Terminal_Id' destination='bus_terminals.Bus_Terminal_Id' %}" id = "find_travel_form">
```

And then my urls.py at the project folder:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^master/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('bus_reservation_system.urls')),
    url(r'^(?P<travel_date>\w+)/travel_date/(?P<origin>\w+)/origin/(?P<destination>\w+)/destination$', include('bus_reservation_system.urls')),

]
```

And then my urls.py at the app folder:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

app_name = "brats"

urlpatterns = [         
    url(r'^', views.index, name = "index"),
    url(r'^(?P<travel_date>\w+)/travel_date/(?P<origin>\w+)/origin/(?P<destination>\w+)/destination', views.get_travel_details, name = "get_travel_details"),
    ]
```

The parameters: travel_date, origin, destination should be a string value to be passed.

And this is my views.py looks:

```
def get_travel_details(request, travel_date, origin, destination):
    errors = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.POST.get('travel_date', ''):
            errors.append('Please determine your date of travel.\n')
        if not request.POST.get('origin', ''):
            errors.append('Please determine your point of origin.\n')
        if not request.POST.get('destination', ''):
            errors.append('Please determine your point of destination.\n')

        if not errors:
            all_bus =  bus.objects.all()

        elif errors:
            travel_schedules = travel_schedule.objects.all()
            bus_terminals = bus_terminal.objects.all()
            bus_types = bus_type.objects.all()

            data = {'travel_schedules': travel_schedules, 'bus_terminals': bus_terminals, 'errors': errors}
            return render(request, 'pages/index.html', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url is still passing in strings, that include a `.`, which isn't included in your regex. I doubt that you actually want the dot and have a string id so just remove the quotes..

So change

```
{% url 'brats:get_travel_details' travel_date='travel_date' origin='bus_terminals.Bus_Terminal_Id' destination='bus_terminals.Bus_Terminal_Id' %}
```

to

```
{% url 'brats:get_travel_details' travel_date='travel_date' origin=bus_terminals.Bus_Terminal_Id destination=bus_terminals.Bus_Terminal_Id %}
```

<sub>And make sure that `Bus_Terminal_Id`'s don't have any non-word characters</sub>

Comment: Still the same error, mate.
Here's an example of `Bus_Terminal_Id` that will came from the database:
**bt-0001** **bt-0002**
also added this to the url's parameters with `[\w-]+` instead of `\w+` only

Comment: @Oli - well those id's contain non-word characters. `[\w\d-]+` would be a better match for those instead of `\w+`

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

To fix the error, remove the following line from your main urls:

```
url(r'^(?P<travel_date>\w+)/travel_date/(?P<origin>\w+)/origin/(?P<destination>\w+)/destination$', include('bus_reservation_system.urls')),
```

---

**Explanation**

You have two urls pointing to the same app. So, everytime you write `{% url 'brats:get_travel_details' ...}`, Django resolves it to the **last registered url** which, in your case is this:

```
url(r'^(?P<travel_date>\w+)/travel_date/(?P<origin>\w+)/origin/(?P<destination>\w+)/destination$', include('bus_reservation_system.urls')),
```

Which finally gets resolved to this:

```
'(?P<travel_date>\w+)/travel_date/(?P<origin>\w+)/origin/(?P<destination>\w+)/destination/(?P<travel_date>\w+)/travel_date/(?P<origin>\w+)/origin/(?P<destination>\w+)/destination'
```

As you can see, the final resolved url requires 6 parameters but you're only passing it 3.

Which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: removed it from the urls.py of project folder. still the same, mate.